# Python and Tkinter changing dictionary to variables

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to activate a set of default values in a group of check boxes that I have. Now instead of setting each default to 1 individually. I was wondering if there is a way to assign all my variables to a dictionary so that I can loop from the dictionary all my variables and set them to 1 instead of writing them individually. This way I can manipulate the group of variables through the app as a group.

Current code:

```
if self.mastervar.get() == 1:

            self.var1.set(1)
            self.var2.set(1)
            self.var3.set(1)
            self.var4.set(1)
            self.var5.set(1)
            self.var6.set(1)
            self.var7.set(1)
```

Failed code:

```
values {'self.var1',
            'self.var2',
            'self.var3',            
            'self.var4', 
            'self.var5', 
            self.var6', 
            self.var7'}
for x in values: 
       locals()[values[x]]
       values[x].set(1)
```

Comment: You can do that with a list too or whatever you want. But in none of these cases your program gains more performance.

Answer (score 0):

Store the actual variables rather than the names of the variables:

```
values = [self.var1, self.var2, self.var3, ...]
for var in values:
    var.set(1)
```

Of course, once you do that there's no reason to keep each variable as a separate attribute:

```
# in initialization code:
values = []
for i in range(10):
    values.append(StringVar())
...
CheckButton(..., variable=values[0], ...)
CheckButton(..., variable=values[1], ...)
...
```